# How to change maximum number of POST variable in PHP?

Tags: php, post, wamp

I'm using WAMP in my local machine, when a FORM(method="POST") with 2000 input fields is submitted I'm able to read only 1001 _POST variable. i.e With Netbeans debugger I can clearly see _POST size is always 1001 if there are more than 1001 input fields in the form.

The same is working fine in another machine(WAMP), where I can see all the POST variables.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Why not take the php.ini from the other machine and compare it to your current machine and see what should be put for the `post_max_size` etc variables?

Comment: Are you using Suhosin (Hardened PHP)?

Comment: I don't know if that's php or the web browser limiting...

Comment: @Lenny, it could be, however, I think the `post_max_size` variable affects this and increasing that should resolve the issue. Since it works on another setup, as stated by the OP, chances are the new install has a smaller `post_max_size` set and that just needs to be increased.

Comment: Web browser never strips post vars. Recen versions of PHP restated max_input_vars http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/php-vulnerability-may-halt-millions-of-servers-max-input-vars so it might affect you. Check if you really need 2000 vars (many firewalls do such filtering as well, so your code might not be portable)

Comment: post_max_size = 81M in working machine, I changed this value and restarted wamp, still problem exists.
I'm not using Suhosin, installed WAMP that's all.
I tried using Chrome and Firefox. No difference.

Comment: @Brad F Jacobs Good to know because I think I ran into this problem i while back and just though it was the web browser :)

Comment: Is it? I tried with IE,Chrome and Firefox. I suspect server settings.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

PHP 5.3.9 introduced the `max_input_vars` config option, which is defaulted to a value of 1000. Check out the [Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) section of the PHP manual. The default value and the change log are at the top of the page.

The value can be changed by updating the server's php.ini, adding an .htaccess file, or [adding a line to httpd.conf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

Comment: Credit goes to a co-worker who had this problem just yesterday and then was nice enough to share his findings with the team :)

Comment: For somebody searching in the future, I found that a default cPanel server as of 2013-03-15 limited the number of input variables to 512. Some of our scripts passed significantly more than that and adding max_input_vars to php.ini fixed the problem.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) with Hardened PHP, you might be hitting a maximum variables limit that it imposes. In your php.ini, you can just add

```
[suhosin]
suhosin.request.max_vars = 1000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 1000
```

changing `1000` to whatever you want and restart your webserver.

I ran into this on the Drupal Permissions page when there were a lot of modules installed with a large number of roles, which resulted in a ton of checkboxes. It would only save a certain number of them before anything after would just get ignored.

It sounds like this is probably not your problem, but since it's fairly likely that someone in the future may stumble upon this when searching for something related I'll go ahead and throw this in since it took me ages to figure out when I was stumped.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using Suhosin.

Comment: There is no suhosin for php5.4 or php5.5 :(

Answer (score 9):

I solved my $_POST max inputs -problem by adding the following to php.ini:

```
max_input_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
```

Note the suhosin.request.max_vars also.

Comment: `max_input_vars` was a perfect fit in my case :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. Open the PHP.INI configuration file and add these lines

[suhosin]

suhosin.post.max_vars = 20000

suhosin.request.max_vars = 20000

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the problem is with the amount of data coming with your POST request. There is no setting which limits the number of $_POST vars that can be set. However there is a memory limit for POST data which is 8MB by default.

In your php.ini file try modifying the value of `post_max_size` and set it to a higher value.  Don't forget to restart apache after the change is made.

Comment: I modified post_max_size to 81M also 0 and restarted WAMP still the problem exists.