# PHP - Form won't submit if too many input fields

Tags: php, submit, max, variables

I recently transferred files from WAMP to a production server that I am setting up. Several forms that were previously working no longer submit. I have been able to deduce that it only happens when there are over a certain number of fields being submitted. The number of fields varies per page but stays consistent within the given page. I have been the the php.ini for both WAMP and my server and have not been able to locate what is causing this behavior. Changing max post size and max input vars did not help. I would post my php.ini but it is almost 2000 lines long.

Comment: have you tried print_r($_REQUEST) at the top to see if they actually come through?

Comment: If it's PHP 5.3.9+, then this is a dupe question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399315/how-to-increase-maximum-post-variable-in-php

Comment: How big are these forms, I can't say even with my largest of forms have I ever run into an issue like this involving a POST method (GET yea sure many of times but not POST). I can however picture maybe a server timing out either due to PHP config or server config. Do you see an actual Error anywhere? We need a little something more than just this description.. its kind of open ended.

Comment: There are no actual errors. One form has 1200 variables and the other has a little over 2000. There is no specific code which is causing the issue so i'm not sure what to provide.