# cakephp controller missing post data

Tags: cakephp

I have a cakephp 2.3 (and now 2.4) web application. The app posts some data to one controller via ajax.
The data is something like this:

```
{
invoice : {id:1 , date:2013-10-22},
content : {
          0 : {amount:500, uid: 32}
          1 : {amount:600, uid: 33}
          }
}
```

When the "content" has less than 155 items the controller saves the data as expected. When the "content" is bigger somehow some part of the data is missing. If I check at the very first line of my controller the $this->request->data array (and $_POST also) has no "invoice" key, and "content" array has only the first 155 items, and the "id" key and its value for item 156.

So Firebug shows all my data as posted to the server, but the controller sees only some part. How could I debug this?

Comment: You might have run into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399315/how-to-increase-maximum-post-variable-in-php

Comment: Thanks. It was PHP max_input_vars setting.