# Set suhosin.request.max_vars in MAMP with PHP 5.5.10

Tags: php, variables, ini

In need to set these variables in php.ini for MAMP running php 5.5.10

```
suhosin.request.max_vars = 1000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 1000
```

As usual I opened and edited the php.ini file to add these 2 lines.

Problem is that it takes not effect in my phpinfo page. The variable are not added at all.

I read in this comment that suhosin is not working anymore in php 5.5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399315/how-to-increase-maximum-post-variable-in-php)

Is that right? 
What can I do?