# $_POST limitations in terms of number of fields

Tags: php, html, forms, post, http-method

My php version is 5.4.16

I have a form with 2500 fields. That sounds weird, but actually I have
an excel sheet. I read the sheet and display all data in an HTML table
whose each cell has a hidden field so that I would be able to post all
the data and do further.

Issue: $_POST remains empty when I post the form with 2500 fields.
When is delete some the fields or remove some columns from excel sheet
which results in less number of fields in the $_POST,then it works fine.

Question: Is there any limit in $_POST for the number of fields being
posted?

Comment: `max_input_vars` defaults to 1000, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399315/how-to-increase-maximum-post-variable-in-php

Comment: Yes i read this just before i posted the issue. I tried to search max_input_vars in my .ini but it was not there.

Comment: Did a binary search to zero in on the effective limit not work?

Comment: Did not get what you said? can you please elaborate?

Comment: ITS NOT THERE? THEN ITS DEFAULT=1000. ADD IT.

Comment: @hanshenrik please turn off your capslock.  it looks like you are yelling

Answer (score 0):

its probably some of these: max_input_nesting_level , max_input_vars , max_input_time , post_max_size

increase them all, try something like

```
max_input_nesting_level = 9999
max_input_vars = 9999
max_input_time = -1
post_max_size = 9999M
```

in php.ini