# web services large data json response - data fetch issue

Tags: php, json, php-ini

I have write Php web services to fetch all user details.

it return Data in Json format ,out put like this .

```
{
    "id": "10",
    "name": "arun",
    "mobile": "0000555666"
},{
    "id": "11",
    "name": "Joy",
    "mobile": "0000555111"
},
```

Right now issue was , if database have more than 1000 user ,API can't get data,loading screen and stuck after some time .
Please help solve out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update "max_input_vars" to higher values in php.ini file. Or you can put "php_value max_input_vars 8000" this line of code in .htacess file as well.

Please refer link for more details [How to increase maximum POST variable in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399315/how-to-increase-maximum-post-variable-in-php)